# asynchronous sub-queries with knex

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, knex.js

The issue here is not with `knex` but with using it along with `async`/`await`. With that out of the way, here is a simple example:

```
const subquery = catchAsync(async () => {
  const res = await knex("author").select("id").where("id", ">", 1);

  return res;
});

const knexQuery = catchAsync(async () => {
  const res = await knex("author").where("id", "in", await subquery());

  return res;
});

const test = catchAsync(async (knexQuery) => {
  const res = await knexQuery();

  console.log(res)

  knex.destroy();
});
```

I can't figure out how to pass the `subquery` to `knexQuery` so it will be resolved at the right moment. Currently its returning an empty array, here's debug log:

```
{
  method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '00baf1e0-81a5-11ea-9b17-3bbd9f85a577',
  sql: 'select `id` from `author` where `id` > ?'
}
{
  method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ],
  __knexQueryUid: '00bc7880-81a5-11ea-9b17-3bbd9f85a577',
  sql: 'select * from `author` where `id` in (?, ?, ?)'
}
(empty array)
```

I thought that I'm `await`ing in all the right places. Obviously I do not. What did I miss?

Note: I'm specifically interested in using `async`/`await` here, not promises.

Comment: Did you try it without using `catchAsync`?

Comment: I shouldn't affect anything as its a simple `try`/`catch` helper. Either way, I tried just now and it still comes back with an empty array.

Comment: Yes, but you should be using plain calls when trying to debug the issue until you find the culprit. You should create a simple query and make sure the connection object is actually connecting to the database.

Comment: See the debug output, there's nothing about not reaching db (which is sqlite, no issues with connecting to a file). Moreover, the `id`'s in the second block come from the db, and match the query as well - connection is fine and response is coming back. Only I can't return it properly.

Comment: Actually, now you're mentioning about the debug log, I see that the bindings on the second query are starting from `2`, so I assume that the `subquery` is returning IDs `> 1`. Is this correct? Do you have `4` records inside `authors` table?

Comment: yes, 4 unique records. On a different note, this works fine if I write `subquery` and `knexQuery` as plain functions - that's why I think the issue is with how I use `async`/`await`.

Comment: I see why it's not working. You're passing a parameter `knexQuery` to `test` async function, thus this is trying to execute it instead of the actual `knexQuery` function. How do you call the `test` function? Try to remove that `async (knexQuery) =>` to see if it's working.

Comment: I simply invoke it with the query, like: `test(knexQuery)`. Stripping all asynchronous bits of `test` didn't help - now the query just fall through and hits `knex.destroy()`, resulting in `Error: aborted`. Stripping asynchronicity from `subquery` does make it work though. Frankly, this is merely a little test project to understand `knex` so I don't have a pressure to fix it right this moment. I would like to understand why I it works with synchronous `subquery` but not with it `async` variation.

Comment: I never had any issues invoking knex using async/await, that's why this is a strange case...  Comment if you ever get your hands to it and upload it on a repo or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return a query builder from an async function without triggering the query, you need to wrap the builder into an object.

Here are some links to a somewhat related discussions in knex issues https://github.com/knex/knex/pull/2226#issuecomment-329589115

Something like this:

```
const subquery = catchAsync(async () => {
  return {
    subQuery: knex("author").select("id").where("id", ">", 1)
  };
});

const knexQuery = catchAsync(async () => {
  const res = await knex("author").where("id", "in", (await subquery()).subQuery);

  return res;
});

const test = catchAsync(async (knexQuery) => {
  const res = await knexQuery();

  console.log(res)

  await knex.destroy();
});
```

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman! This solves the issue albeit it creates more confusion in my poor head (how does `await subquery()).subQuery` works? `subquery` is not a function, no?). I've so much more to learn!

Comment: On a different note, I run into another issue with `async`/`await` (described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/g48oed/node_esm_asyncawait_knex_promise_pending/) to which I tried to apply approach from your answer but that didn't got me anywhere. If you have some spare time and could take a look at it I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: I answered to reddit too, might sound rude but no offense really, just wrote that in a hurry :)

Comment: No offense taken :-)